# Navigation background button hover upwards

Tags: html, css

I have this horizontal menu. The menu looks like tabs and are 29px high. The image is set to `<li>` background image in CSS. And I set the hover also in CSS.
Now what I want is when we have a mouse over that the image moves upwards with 8px. Now it moves downwards.

CODE:

```
#nav li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    width:116px;
    height:29px;
    background-image:url(images/nav/nav_btn.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:8px;}

#nav li:hover {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    width:116px;
    height:37px;
    background-image:url(images/nav/nav_btn_active.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:-8px;}

<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse your padding on the `li:hover`

```
padding-top:-8px;
padding-bottom:8px;
```

EDIT: NOT! Of course, I don't know where my brain was when I stated the above. There is no such thing as negative `padding`. I think this is what you desire:

```
#nav li:hover {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    width:116px;
    height:37px;
    background-image:url(images/nav/nav_btn_active.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. That was not good (that's what I get for answering without actually testing). See my edited revision. It should solve it.

Comment: That did the job! Thanks man. Would you also by any chance know how I could get 1 tab get in the active state when your on that page.
So, you know on wich page you are. Thanks again!

Comment: There are various ways of doing it. Try looking at this search stackoverflow.com/search?q=pure+css+page+navigation+active

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest getting rid of padding-top and -bottom, and using background-position instead? Also you don't actually need to add to `#nav li:hover` the rules you have already defined under `#nav li` as the rules are cascaded.